# I had a problem when switching from URDF to XACRO

Tags: urdf, xacro, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!!!

I had a problem when switching from URDF to XACRO.
I did a urdf check: `$ check_urdf pan_tilt_generated.urdf`, before generating this: `$ pan_tilt_generated.urdf` using this command: `$ rosrun xacro xacro pan_tilt.xacro --inorder> pan_tilt_generated.urdf.`

I can’t find a solution yet. any ideas?

Here such an error is issued by verification:

```
 ace@ace:~/catkin_ws/src/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/urdf$ check_urdf pan_tilt_generated.urdf 
  Error:   radius [] is not a valid float at line 187 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/link.cpp
    Error:   Could not parse visual element for Link [base_link]  at line 452 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parse/src/link.cpp
    robot name is: pan_tilt
   ---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
  root Link: base_link has 1 child(ren)
     child(1):  pan_link
        child(1):  tilt_link
```

These errors get the launch of the launch file:

```
   [ERROR] [1585602978.236429024]: radius [] is not a valid float]
  [ERROR] [1585602978.237213943]: Could not parse visual element for Link [base_link]
```

but RVIZ, it works and shows the model without errors

this is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="pan_tilt">
  <xacro:property name="base_link_length" value="1" />
  <xacro:property name="base_link_radius" value="2" />

 <xacro:property name="pan_link_length" value="2" />
 <xacro:property name="pan_link_radius" value="1"/>

 <xacro:property name="tilt_link_length" value="2"/>
 <xacro:property name="tilt_link_radius" value="1"/>


 <xacro:macro name="inertial_matrix" params="mass">
      <inertial>
     <mass value="${mass}" />
     <inertia ixx="0.5" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.5" iyz="0.0"
          izz="0.5" />
  </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <link name="base_link">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
  <cylinder length="${base_link_length}" radius="${base_link_radius}"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <material name="yellow">
  <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
  <cylinder length="${base_link_length+0.02}" radius="2"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </collision>
 <xacro:inertial_matrix mass="1"/>
 </link>
 <joint name="pan_joint" type="revolute">
   <parent link="base_link"/>
   <child link="pan_link"/>
   <origin xyz="0 0 0.1"/>
   <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
   <limit effort="300" velocity="0.1" lower="-3.14" upper="3.14"/>
   <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
</joint>
<link name="pan_link">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
  <cylinder length="${pan_link_length}" radius="${pan_link_radius}"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
    <material name="red">
      <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
  <cylinder length="${pan_link_length}" radius="${pan_link_radius+2}"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
 </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_matrix mass="1"/>
</link>
<joint name="tilt_joint" type="revolute">
  <parent link="pan_link"/>
  <child link="tilt_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.2"/>
  <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
  <limit effort="300" velocity=".1" lower="-4.64" upper="-1.5"/>
  <dynamics damping="50" friction="1"/>
</joint>
<link name="tilt_link">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
   <cylinder length="${tilt_link_length}" radius="${tilt_link_radius}"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <material name="green">
  <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
  <cylinder length="${tilt_link_length}" radius="${tilt_link_radius+2}"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 1.5 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </collision>
      <xacro:inertial_matrix mass="1"/>
 </link>
</robot>
```

I changed all the values to integers in the variable radius, nothing has changed, it turns out the same error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347919/i-had-a-problem-when-switching-from-urdf-to-xacro./) by [Ace_Eca](https://answers.ros.org/users/51927/ace_eca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works fine on my machine, so I'm guessing the problem is your launch file. Make sure you are running xacro in your launch file. See also: http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ace_Eca](https://answers.ros.org/users/51927/ace_eca/) on 2020-03-31**:
Hello,
my launch.

```
<launch>
<arg name="model"/>
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find  astering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/pan_tilt.xacro" />

<param name="use_gui" value="true"/>

<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
<node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/config/urdf.rviz"  required="true" />
</launch>
```

**Comment by [Ace_Eca](https://answers.ros.org/users/51927/ace_eca/) on 2020-03-31**:
I can not find an explanation for this error, my code starts and works.

```
 [ ERROR] [1585602978.236429024]: radius [] is not a valid float]
  [ERROR] [1585602978.237213943]: Could not parse visual element for Link [base_link]
```

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-03-31**:
I still cannot replicate your error. What version of ROS are you using?

**Comment by [Ace_Eca](https://answers.ros.org/users/51927/ace_eca/) on 2020-03-31**:\

- /rosdistro: kinetic
- /rosversion: 1.12.14